# Set width to widest element while still having floats

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have a sidebar with a container with buttons, on the first line there is an element that floats left and an element that floats right. Below them are buttons with various lengths, one button per line. Everything is in the container. How can I make it so all buttons and the container are the length of the widest button? Floating an element to the right makes the container as wide as the sidebar, that should be the max width, not the default one. I can accept an answer in JavaScript as well as CSS.

Here is what I've done so far: https://jsfiddle.net/ke2b7wq1/

css:

```
#sidebar{
width: 250px;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
#left-float{
padding: 0 5px;
background: #F00;
float: left;
}
#right-float{
padding: 0 5px;
background: #F00;
float: right;
}
.button{
text-align: center;
background: #BBB;
clear: both;
float: left;
margin-top: 7px;
width: 100%;
}
.pusher{
clear: both;
height: 0;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="sidebar">
<div id="container">
    <div id="left-float">hello</div>
    <div id="right-float">0</div>
    <div class="button">lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="button">dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="button">foo bar foo bar</div>
    <div class="button">lorizzle ipizzle</div>
    <div class="button">final button</div>
    <div class="pusher"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle/codepen example

Comment: Provide code, no matter in what platform. But we aren't wizards to see your code remotely

Comment: you want the width of all the button as long as the container's width? if that just set the width of them to 100%

Comment: Does it have to involve floats? There are other options. What level of browser support do you need....but the other commenters are right, we need to see actual *code*...ideally in a Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `#container` to `display:inline-block` or `float:left` (don't forget to clear the floats).

**Floated**

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#container {
  float: left;
}
#left-float {
  padding: 0 5px;
  background: #F00;
  float: left;
}
#right-float {
  padding: 0 5px;
  background: #F00;
  float: right;
}
.button {
  text-align: center;
  background: #BBB;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px;
}
.pusher {
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="left-float">hello</div>
    <div id="right-float">0</div>
    <div class="button">lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="button">dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="button">foo bar foo bar</div>
    <div class="button">lorizzle ipizzle</div>
    <div class="button">final button</div>
    <div class="pusher"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Inline-block**

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#sidebar{
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;

}

#container {
    display:inline-block;
}
#left-float{
    padding: 0 5px;
    background: #F00;
    float: left;
}
#right-float{
    padding: 0 5px;
    background: #F00;
    float: right;
}
.button{
    text-align: center;
    background: #BBB;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 7px;
    width: 100%;
    padding:4px;
}
.pusher{
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="left-float">hello</div>
        <div id="right-float">0</div>
        <div class="button">lorem ipsum</div>
        <div class="button">dolor sit amet</div>
        <div class="button">foo bar foo bar</div>
        <div class="button">lorizzle ipizzle</div>
        <div class="button">final button</div>
        <div class="pusher"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in your fiddle css code

```
#container {display: inline-block;}
```